# How do I get GetResourceStream to read files that have an extension other than .txt?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I have the following code:

```
 var resource = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("movies.txt", UriKind.Relative));
 StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
 string z = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

When I change the `movies.txt` extension to `movies.plist`, the code no longer functions, even though the file is still plain text. How do I solve this? I need to keep the file extension as .plist.

The error I get is `NullReferenceException` on the second line.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `StreamReader` (except inasmuch as it complains when you pass it null).  Your problem is in `GetResourceStream` (that it returns null).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the System.IO.FileInfo class to open a file. That will let you open a FileStream.

```
var file = new System.IO.FileInfo("c:\foo.bar");
var FileStream = file.OpenRead();
Byte b = (Byte)FileStream.ReadByte();
Debug.WriteLine(b.ToString());
```

Edit: Corrected code.

Comment: I'm showing that FileStream.ReadByte() returns an int, not a byte.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. It does return an integer, which represents the byte value read from the file. Just needed to cast the Int32 to a Byte, if that's the format you wanted it in.

Comment: I don't have the exact path of the file, since it's included in the VS project. Any ideas on how to access that file from this FileInfo function?

Comment: You can just reference the file name without the drive name, and it will look in the processes' working directory for the file. You can discover the processes' working directory using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. There is a property on `Process` called `StartInfo`, which returns a `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` object, which has a `WorkingDirectory` property.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I realized after posting this that this solution isn't available in Windows phone environments.

If all you want to do is read a text file it might make more sense to use:

```
string result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("myTextFile.ext");
```

Is there any particular reason you want to use StreamReader specifically?

Comment: Nope. I'm new to Windows programming so it's just the first option I ran across.

Comment: By the way, I'm not showing a "ReadAllText" method as an option on my System.IO.File namespace. Any ideas why? I'm developing for WinPhone7.

Comment: Ah my apologies. I didn't notice that. My bad.